# Python: Request to scrape Google News within a date range not working

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, google-news

I'm trying to scrape news articles from Google News for a specified date range.

```
date_range_param = 'cdr:1,cd_min:07/31/2018,cd_max:08/12/2018'
params = {'q': company_name, 'tbm': 'nws', 'tbs': date_range_param}
page = requests.get("https://www.google.com/search", params=params)
```

I'm using the code above, but it returns the latest news and ignores the date range. What do I have to change to make it work? I've already tried solutions to similar problems, like using the user-agent header, but it still doesn't work as expected.

Comment: I had the same problem scraping using R. To fix it, I simply changed the user-agent string being used when the get request is made. R has a default user-agent (as would any python library), I changed it to the same string found when you google 'what is my user-agent'. Hope this helps